# Hard Drive Recognized Under Certain Conditions

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bios

I've got three hard drives in my Windows 7 box. Last night, my box randomly blue-screened and came up with an awful "Bootmgr is missing" message. After some looking, I reseated a couple of the cables and it seemed to go away.

The current problem I'm having is that one of the *other* drives (not my main one, though I'm not 100% sure the boot sector isn't on this one) won't show up in Windows at boot. I can "scan for hardware changes" and it'll come up as normal, but it doesn't show up by default. If I go into the BIOS, it's not available as a boot drive either, but I'm not 100% sure it was before. Here's the thing: **changing the SATA ports to allow hot-plugging (from the BIOS) fixes the problem**, and the drives all show up on boot in Windows. But that doesn't seem right, since I don't think that was on at any point in the past.

So my real question is, does this sound like (with the information availabe):

- A bad configuration (BIOS/OS)?
- The beginnings of a failing hard drive?
- A bad SATA cable?
- A bad power cable?

I've only had limited time to try things out thus far (haven't tried changing cables yet) but I want to get on buying a new drive if this kind of thing is likely an impending failure.

Comment: You might try testing the HD's with something like DFT.  It couldn't hurt anything at this point.  http://www.hgst.com/support/downloads/#DFT

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like bad cables, missing data some times, but as soon as you jiggle the cables it works? Totally bad cables, you should inspect them for any missing plastic coating, and depending on how cheap you are, either buy new cables, or use electric tape to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Is windows hiding your drive?

1. Start Explorer.
2. Go to Organize > Folder and search options, View Tab
3. Uncheck: Hide empty drives in the Computer folder.

Comment: The drive isn't empty; it's been in use and has lots of files on it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect the PSU and brownouts. POST is a fairly demanding time for the PSU, everything must come on to be tested. If it brown-outs a drive might not be detected properly and thus missed as the BOOT process attempts to hand off to an OS.

This might also explain why enabling hot-swap fixes it, because it is always able to accept a new drive for use.

Alternatively, test all drives with something like Lifeguard, Seatools, EBCD.

Swap the PSU if you have a known good spare, see if it helps.